# Finding patients who went under vasopressor use in MIMIC-III

Tags: mimic-iii

I am interested in exploring Vasopressor use in `MIMIC-III`. I googled Vasopressor some drugs. I also tried to identify the relevant `itemid` in the `d_items` table. I figured out that those Vasopressor drugs are also existing in the `MIMIC-III`. Those are `"Isuprel","Nitroglycerine","Dopamine","Dopamine Drip","Levophed","Epinephrine-k","Phenylephrine","Epinephrine","Dobutamine Drip","Levophed-k","Epinephrine Drip","Nitroglycerin","Vasopressin","Lidocaine","Insulin","Nitroglycerine-k","Dobutamine","Milrinone","Norepinephrine"`. 
 
 I am wondering if it is reasonable to consider them all as vasopressor drug and to consider those `itemid` as vasopressor drugs in my research.

Answer (score 1):

Insulin and lidocaine are not vasopressors - but the rest are. Determining which vasopressors to include is more determined by the research project rather than a global ground truth - sometimes you'd include inotropes, sometimes not, and so on.

Comment: Additionally, nitroglycerine is not a vasopressor. Isuprel is really used more as a chronotropic agent. And while epinephrine drip is certainly a vasopressor, it can also be given subcutaneously or as a push in the setting of a cardiac arrest or anaphylaxis, which may not be the use cases you are thinking about.

Comment: Good points all around!